# Changing colour of specific data

Tags: html, css, json, angular

I want to change the colour of some data from my json file.
If I have a dataset that has dates inside and I want the dates that are 2017 in light pink. How can I achieve this without effecting the 2018, 2019 ect. dates.

Json file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "month": "2017-03-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 2,
        "month": "2017-04-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 3,
        "month": "2017-05-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 4,
        "month": "2017-06-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 5,
        "month": "2017-07-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 6,
        "month": "2017-08-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 7,
        "month": "2017-09-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 8,
        "month": "2017-10-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 9,
        "month": "2017-11-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 10,
        "month": "2017-12-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 11,
        "month": "2018-01-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 12,
        "month": "2018-02-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 13,
        "month": "2018-03-01"
    }
]
```

This is the HTML I need editing. I need it so the months that are in 2017 display in light pink.
HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Line 1</th>
    <th *ngFor="let volumes of volumes">{{ volumes.month | uppercase }}</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should finish your Angular tutorial `https://angular.io/tutorial`, as all of what you're asking is written just there.

Comment: check here you will get it https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/

Comment: That is correct except how can I do this with a date. As I want it to occur for all the dates that are in the year 2017. @SuhelKhan

Comment: You can serialize a JS Date from a string with the Date constructor and then get the year of the date with the `.getYear()` method. From there, it's as simplle as `new Date(dateString).getYear() === '2017' ? 'pink': 'not-pink'`. Sounds like a perfect job for a directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass that **Date** in every object to component like below

```js
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  volumes: any[] = [{
      "id": 1,
      "month": "2017-03-01"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "month": "2017-04-01"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "month": "2017-05-01"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "month": "2017-06-01"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "month": "2017-07-01"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "month": "2017-08-01"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "month": "2017-09-01"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "month": "2017-10-01"
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "month": "2017-11-01"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "month": "2017-12-01"
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "month": "2018-01-01"
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "month": "2018-02-01"
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "month": "2018-03-01"
    }
  ];

  checkYear(date) {
    return new Date(date).getFullYear() == 2017 ? true : false;
  }
}
```

```css
.pink-color {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Line 1</th>
    <th *ngFor="let volume of volumes" [ngClass]="{ 'pink-color': checkYear(volume.month) }">
      {{ volume.id }}
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ffi7jj)

Comment: This works perfectly thank you. I just have a small question. If I wanted to have 2018 years a different colour too. How could I add that ?