# Changing Colour of multiple specific data

Tags: html, css, json, angular

Previously I asked the question Changing Colour of Specific Data: [Changing colour of specific data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51481515/changing-colour-of-specific-data/51485232#51485232)

However now I have a question relating to that. 
Now that I have the 2017 dates in pink, I want the 2018 dates in blue. How can I add a second date. Better yet how can I make it alternate through different colours for every year without manually inputting each year. 
For now though I will just like to know how to add a second year to the previous solution.

Json file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "month": "2017-03-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 2,
        "month": "2017-04-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 3,
        "month": "2017-05-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 4,
        "month": "2017-06-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 5,
        "month": "2017-07-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 6,
        "month": "2017-08-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 7,
        "month": "2017-09-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 8,
        "month": "2017-10-01"
    }
    {
        "id": 9,
        "month": "2017-11-01"
    }
]
```

I thought maybe a switch case might help but this is what I have in my HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Line 1</th>
    <th *ngFor="let volumes of volumes" [ngClass]="{ 'pink-color': checkYear(volumes.month) }">{{ volumes.month | uppercase }}</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Component.ts:

```
checkYear(date) {
        return new Date(date).getFullYear() == 2017 ? true : false;
}
```

CSS:

```
.pink-color {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking year in `ngClass`. return class name in `ngClass` function as per year.

Try this

```
 [ngClass]="getClass(volumes.month)"
```

In cpmponent

```
getClass(date) {
  var year new Date(date).getFullYear();
  if(year == 2017){
    return "pink-color"
  }
  if(year == 2018){
    return "blue-color"
  }
  /*if needed can add more like yellow for 2019*/
  return "";//for other years
}
```

And you can add a class for blue color

```
.blue-color {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you